# Open web popup from WPF application and close it with javascript

Tags: javascript, wpf, popup, .net-3.5

I have a WPF application that communicates with some 3rd party server.

After the user completed some task in the WPF tool, I need to display a specific web site from the server in a popup window. The popup must be closed using one of the buttons on the site (which will confirm another task). But when javascript wants to close that window, Internet Explorer will normally open a dialog box and ask the user to confirm closing the popup.

I am looking for a simple solution to disable this dialog box. I can't change the behaviour of the server so I need to work around it.

My old approach with the annoying confirmation dialog was to run iexplore.exe with the popups URL as parameter (via `System.Diagnostics.Process`).

My new approach is a hidden `<Frame x:Name="PopupFrame" />` element. When the popup should be openend I set the `Source` attribute of the PopupFrame to a page that opens the popup. Thus the popup has a base window and javascript can close it without the confirmation dialog. However this doesn't work on several systems (Probably because of some security settings) and it involves another page that does the redirect/popup.

Is there an easier way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** Ok, I just realized you don't have control over the web page, I can only think of injecting some javascript to the page, add an event handler to the WebBrowser's LoadCompleted event and inject the javascript there, this should take care of it and not require you to modify the original web page:

```
// Add a reference to Microsoft.mshtml
using mshtml;

// inside the window constructor after you set 
// the webBrowser's ObjectForScripting property
this.webBrowser.LoadCompleted += this.webBrowser_LoadCompleted;

void webBrowser_LoadCompleted(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    var doc = (HTMLDocument)webBrowser.Document;
    var head = doc.getElementsByTagName("head").Cast<HTMLHeadElement>().First();
    var script = (IHTMLScriptElement)doc.createElement("script");
    script.text = 
        "javascript:window.onbeforeunload = function () { window.external.Close(); }";
    head.appendChild((IHTMLDOMNode)script);
}
```

---

It sounds like you own the webpage you are opening so here is what you can do:

1.- Add a Popup control to your window  and add a WebBrowser control to it, you'll use this to navigate to your page:

```
<Button Content="Button" Click="button1_Click" />
<Popup x:Name="PopUp" Width="300" Height="300">
        <WebBrowser x:Name="webBrowser">
        </WebBrowser>
</Popup>
```

2.- Create a new class and add the [ComVisible(true)] attribute to it. It should include a reference of your Popup control object. Add a public method to your new class that hides the Popup control.

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;

[ComVisible(true)]
public class ScriptHandler
{
    private Popup popup;
    public ScriptHandler(Popup popup)
    {
        this.popup = popup;
    }

    public void Close()
    {
        this.popup.IsOpen = false;
    }
}
```

3.- Set the WebBrowser control's ObjectForScripting property to an instance of your new class.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private ScriptHandler scriptHandler;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.scriptHandler = new ScriptHandler(this.PopUp);
        this.webBrowser.ObjectForScripting = this.scriptHandler;
    }

    // Shows the pop up and navigates to your page
    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.webBrowser.Navigate("http://localhost:56977/PopUp.htm");
        this.PopUp.IsOpen = true;
    }
}
```

4.- Since you registered the ScriptHandler object with the WebBrowser control all public methods in this class can be accessed from javascript, add a javascript method to your page (you may need to verify the 'undefined' validation I'm doing) that calls the Close method in your ComVisible class:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function CloseMe()
    {
        if(window.external != null && window.external.CloseMe != 'undefined')
        {
            window.external.Close();
        }
    }
</script>
```

5.- Add a link that calls the javascript CloseMe method to your page:

```
<a href='javascript:CloseMe()'>Close Me</a>
```

As you probably realized already this solution will work not only with a Popup control, you can also instantiate a new Window and close it, dispose of your WeBrowser control etc. or just Show/Hide a different type of control.

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer, but it's more complicated than the current approach, which just works.

Comment: No problem, although this should work across different systems (which I believe was your original problem). But I feel you, working across WPF-javascript is kind of a pain.